# Optimize javascript if else 18 times

Tags: javascript, optimization

I am trying to create a golf scorecard and are able to do so like this:

```
if(i == 0){
    totalpoints = pp0[0];   
} else if(i == 1){
    totalpoints = pp0[0]+pp0[1];    
} else if(i == 2){
    totalpoints = pp0[0]+pp0[1]+pp0[2]; 
} else if(i == 3){
    totalpoints = pp0[0]+pp0[1]+pp0[2]+pp0[3];  
}....
```

This off course goes on 18 times? making each line even longer... How can I do this more optimized?

Hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Use a loop: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for. This question seems to be a be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this:

```
for (var j=0;j<i+1;j++) {
    totalpoints += pp0[j];
}
```

Comment: Everyone was perfect, allthough this one remembered to add 1 to the i :-)

Comment: @Mansa - `j <= i` would be better though

Answer (score 4):

Where i is your existing variable:

```
var totalpoints = 0;
for(var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    totalpoints += pp0[j];
}
```

This is pretty much what arrays were invented for!

Comment: A couple of seconds ahead :))

Comment: …and not forgetting the initialisation with zero. +1!

Answer (score 2):

It's like you're doing a sum, so you can use the built-in `reduce` function in JavaScript:

```
totalpoints = pp0.reduce(function (prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur;
}, 0);
```

This will go through all elements in pp0 and return a sum. If, however, you want only the first n parts of pp0, use a slice:

```
totalpoints = pp0.slice(0, n).reduce(function (prev, cur) {
    return prev + cur;
}, 0);
```

See [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for details and browser compatibility.

**Note:**

This solution assumes that you're using a real array (`Array.isArray()`) and relatively new browser features.

Comment: +1 The shame of JavaScript's function syntax is the verbosity in cases like this. Though a named function could help. `pp0.slice(0, n).reduce(sum, 0);`

Comment: @CrazyTrain Yes. I've been messing with Dart recently, and it's much nicer: `totalpoints = pp0.fold((prev, cur) => prev + cur);` (this exact thing is an [example](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_core/List.html#fold))

Comment: Are you liking Dart? I've been keeping it in my sights. Such an enormous advantage when you can start from a clean slate. If their JS cross compiler supported IE8, I'd probably start using it today.

Comment: @CrazyTrain - Yes, loving Dart. My sites use HTML5 features not in IE8, so it works out well. Not using it at work though, since it would take too long to rewrite everything... Maybe when they hit 1.0 I'll try to push it at work.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (j=0; j<=i; j++) {
    totalpoints += pp0[j];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

basically what you are doing is doing a sum, so a doing a method might be a good start:

```
function sum(counter)
var sum =0;
for(var i = 0; i < counter ; i++) {
sum+= pp0[i];
}

return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try writing a loop.

```
     totalPoints = 0;

    for(var i=0;i<j;i++)
    {
          totalPoints += pp0[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just want to add up the first `i` values in the `pp0` array, so use a loop:

```
var totalpoints = 0;
for (var index=0; index<i; index++) {
    totalpoints += pp0[index]
}
```